# Marker Google Maps Show/Hide OnClick

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to make google maps project, I was showing my marker on my map.
But now I want to make show/hide marker when I click checkbox,

this my code for showing marker in my maps, data for my marker I get from MySQL,

```
function initialize() { 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: (lat,long)
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});


        var latArea = new Array();

        var longArea = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < $$; i++) //looping until all data from mysql
        {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArea[i], longArea[i]),
                map: map
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent('<b>Coordinat : </b>'+String(latArea[i])+' , '+
                                      String(longArea[i]));
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
  }
```

I was successfully displaying all data to marker in maps and add function for hide/show marker but only one marker is hide/show not all,
this my code for show/hide function

```
function toggleMarker() {
        if (!marker.getVisible()) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
  }
```

Thank you.

i was solving this problem,
this is correct code,

```
<script>
  var markers = new Array();
  function initialize() {

        var latArea = new Array();

        var longArea = new Array();

        var i, newMarker;

        for (i = 0; i < $$; i++) 
        { 
            newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArea[i], longArea[i]),
                map: map,
                icon: icon,

            newMarker.category = 'show';
            newMarker.setVisible(false);

            markers.push(newMarker);

        }

  }

  function displayMarkers(obj,category) {
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < $$; i++)
         {   
            if (markers[i].category === category) {
                if ($(obj).is(":checked")) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    markers[i].setVisible(false);    
                }
            } else {
                markers[i].setVisible(false);
            }
         }
  }
```

and this checkbox in html for show/hidden marker

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="displayMarkers(this,'area');" />
```

Comment: can you please do a check on your `latArea` and `longArea`. And how did you call your `toggleMarker()`?

Comment: To display all markers was sucsesfully including displaying window info, the problem is when it will hide the marker,
its when i call function
"<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglemarker()" />Hidden Area"